# Question about factoring polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring

If I have a binomial $9x^2-16$, and want to factor it I would normally say the answer is $(3x+4)(3x-4)$.

In my math book they factor it down to $(3x+\sqrt 2)(3x-\sqrt 2)$. Can anyone explain to me why this is so?
The question was about writing a polynomial as a product of linear factors.

Comment: Either you misread the binomial, or the book is wrong.  $(3x+\sqrt2)(3x-\sqrt2)\neq9x^2-16$.

Comment: It's $9x^2-2$ from the other line.

Comment: What you wrote down is correct, assuming that the problem is what you told us.

Comment: Books may be full of errors: authors are human, not demigods.